# Google Drive images are sometimes not showing on my website

Tags: image, google-chrome, google-drive-api, http-status-code-403

I have a website with tons of images hosted on Google Drive. I use the `https://drive.google.com/uc?id={IMAGE_FILE_ID}` format as the source of the images.

Usually it works perfectly, but sometimes after a reload the same images which were visible a second ago are just not showing anymore, and from that point on, none of the images can load anymore. In the network log I can see 403 as response.

[image]

What I observed so far (in Chrome):

- I only get this issue in incognito mode
- It only happens after heavy usage of the website (lots of image loading)
- After a certain amount of time (sometimes 30 minutes, sometimes 10 minutes) images start working again
- Even if it stops working in incognito mode, if I open the website in a normal (not incognito) window it works
- It is totally random. Sometimes it stops working after a few minutes sometimes after an hour and everything in between
- If I change to mobile network from the wifi it always starts working again instantly

UPDATE: I was able to get some more detailed information about this by sending the exact same request with Postman. The response from Google is an HTML page saying: `We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't processyour request right now` See picture below:

[image]

<strike>Do you have any suggestions or ideas?</strike> How can I avoid this? How can I convince Google that my users are not sending automated queries, but there is simply a huge amount of images on the website?

Comment: Is the site public? Do you mind sharing a link to it?

Comment: Stack overflow does not like when I share a link, but let's try it and hope I will not get punished. The site is NSFW! Link: https://sextingo.com

Comment: Haha, too scared to click that. What are the details of the 403? Maybe it's a rate limit thing: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/limits

Comment: It is just 403, I do not get any details in the response. Rate limiting is a good idea, but the strange thing is that, if I change to mobile network it always starts working. I do not even have a Google Cloud console to check my current rate.

Comment: Is there any more info in the other sections, like Response?

Comment: Nope, nothing. It is just a plain 403 response.

Comment: @aleksandar Please see my updated answer. I've added details about the error message. You were right, this is indeed a rate limiting thing. My question: what could I do about it?

Comment: You gotta stagger the loading of each 1 of your images. It might not do well for your users to do that. I don't know what the limits are but basically be within that and maybe paginate your images so that only up to that amount loads each time. Then you probably also want to cache whatever was loaded before and not repeat that. Maybe a better solution is to find another host, or host it on your own server.